# Visual Sequence Editor Imports Movie Strip as Too Long

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am trying to add a 21 minute, 58 second MP4 file as a movie strip. When Blender imports it, the file shows as being 3 hours, 28 minutes and 20 seconds. What should I do to correct this?

The file runs fine in Windows Live Movie Maker, VLC, and Windows Media Player.

I tried it in both Blender 2.75 and Blender 2.72 on Windows 7 Home Premium (x64), with both versions giving the same results. I'm not sure why this is happening, though it is worth mentioning that the video has an odd floating-point frame rate of 19.195170 FPS. Rounding this to 20 FPS means that the video should be ~79,080 frames long. Instead, it's hit Blender's absolute maximum length of 300,000 frames long since the full length is apparently 331,120 frames (26.4896 FPS). The pop-up box says this is "The final length after handles are applied," what does that mean? Could it be causing the problem?

The video was created using Mobizen screen recorder on Android, and I managed to process it through WLMM and upload it to YouTube with no issues.

I'm just wondering what could make Blender miscount the frames and video length by such a large margin.

Comment: Have you set your Frame Rate properly in your Render Properties under Dimensions to a Custom Value of the 19.195170 FPS before importing the movie strip into the VSE? You should consider using Handbrake to convert it to a proper frame rate before using it in Blender.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/46752/2843

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/43298/2843

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing mp4 into blender](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47278/importing-mp4-into-blender)